# Jquery Validation : Floating number filed with Positive/Negative with 6 digit 2 decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to restrict my text field to take a float number with 6 numbers and 2 decimal limitation.

Example 123456.12, 222222.22 .

I need to have a maximum of 6 digits before the decimal.
     Number can be positive or negative.

I tried : https://jsfiddle.net/wuL34dto/

```
$('.number').keypress(function(event) {
var $this = $(this);
if ((event.which != 46 || $this.val().indexOf('.') != -1) &&
   ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) &&
   (event.which != 0 && event.which != 8))) {
       event.preventDefault();
}

var text = $(this).val();
if ((event.which == 46) && (text.indexOf('.') == -1)) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if ($this.val().substring($this.val().indexOf('.')).length > 3) {
            $this.val($this.val().substring(0, $this.val().indexOf('.') + 3));
        }
    }, 1);
}

if ((text.indexOf('.') != -1) &&
    (text.substring(text.indexOf('.')).length > 2) &&
    (event.which != 0 && event.which != 8) &&
    ($(this)[0].selectionStart >= text.length - 2)) {
        event.preventDefault();
}      
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should learn about regular expressions :-)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/dist/js/jasny-bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<input class="inputmask">

<script>
$('.inputmask').inputmask({
  mask: '999999.99'
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text.match(^[0-9]{6}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$).length > 0
```

not tested this pattern

or add jquery function

```
$.fn.extend({
    checkinput:function() {
      return text.match(^[0-9]{6}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$).length > 0;
});
```

usage:

```
if(text.checkinput())
```